# How to make NLA strip pick up location based on previous action?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, dopesheet

I am progressing on my complex animation [model](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34730). Now I have just a small problem. I have create 3 action strips: walking, movingstraight and crouch. 
In the NLA editor, i try to compose these actions.

In the first test, I did like this image and the animation correctly works

[image: image1]
Now, I need that the person continue to walk form the current place. I add walking and moving action like this
[image: image2]
the problem that the person return continue to walk but form the first place. I think that i can resolve this by creating an other moving action from the current place to the next place but i think it so complicated if i need to move the person in different place. I hope that the question is not confused.

Comment: Oh boy . . . I think this is too broad, Blender.SE is pointed towards short, specific Q&A style issues, maybe try BlenderArtists with this one. If you run into a specific issue, you can post it here.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, I will try to make my question short.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, I edited my question. Hope to be usefull

Comment: Sounds like [this might help](http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/offset-an-animation-cycle-in-blender/)

Comment: @startingBlender Could you please go through your earlier question and mark some as answered when you got a helpful answer.

Comment: @stacker, Thanks for your help, but my objectif is not to get moving and crouch in the same time. As in a real case, I need to get the person walking then crouch for some time without moving then stand and continue to walk.

Comment: @stacker, I correct the error of scaling and update the file.

Comment: @startingBlender then you could simply key the same position in the motion action.

Comment: @stacker, I did not understand what did you mean ? However, in this new version http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34731 how can I force it to continue to walk from the same place instead of return back. It is what i did not understand.

Comment: I added a new image to my post. Complete file here: http://pasteall.org/blend/34732

Comment: @stacker, could you help me to fix this problem. in this file http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34781, i would that the person turn left and continue to walk but it there a little bit problem that i could understand

Comment: @startingBlender please post a new question, continued discussion of several issues in one post does not fit the Q/A format here. But a quick peek, it seems that you keyframed the rotation of the master in the person1Action (try muting channels to debug)

Comment: @stacker, I mute rotation channel but it does not work. I post my question here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26527/how-to-make-nla-strip-rotate-based-on-previous-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can blend the actions in the properties of the *Action Strip*:

[image]

The extrapolation and blend settings are important.

Result:

[image]

You have keyframed the scale some bones of the upper body in the crouch action (perhaps accidentally) in case you wonder why this looks like this.

[image]

To stop movement while crouching simply keyframe the same position for the frames:

[image]

Comment: Thx very much, so it is equivalent to add a new mouvement action?

Comment: @startingBlender yes you could also create two movement actions and have gap between them.