# How to make NLA strip rotate based on previous action?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, dopesheet

in this file http://pasteall.org/blend/34781, i would that the person turn left and continue to walk but there is a little bit problem that i could understand that canceled the turn left action. Could you help me

Comment: Your blend file link is dead, please reupload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it. You have to cancel the rotation master before starting the new moving cycle. This is my new file [.blender](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34808)

Comment: What do you mean by cancel? removing the rotation channels from master? I think you would be better off using paths with follow path constraints, this should be easier.

Comment: @stacker   Yes, I am thinking about it. I have tried using a bezier curve but I am wondering if I could interpose different actions between extremities.

Comment: @stacker, do have any experience with MakeWalk?

Comment: No, I hadn't much luck with the additional scripts from the makehuman project.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of piling up so many actions it is way easier to control the characters movement by using curves and follow path constraints, the influence of each segment must be defined by keyframing the influence slider and the offset value controls when the curve comes into play.

[image]

This would allow you to order the actions subsequent in a single actions strip. Only one to control the curves influence is added on top.

[image]

One important thing is to start curve 1 with an influence of 1 and setting another keyframe with influence 1 before you set it to 0 when the second path should take over otherwise the values in between would be interpolated.

Also note that the number of frams for the curve can be adjusted in the curves properties:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You have had just a small error about the head rotation in the BezierCurvetodoor.

Comment: I tried to do agin your work using curves. I start simply by using only the first curve. However, I remark that curve did not show in the dopesheet panel and person did not move.

Comment: @startingBlender curves don't have keyframes and therefore don't show up in the dopesheet. The character will only move in the range defined between follow path offset - curve frames.

Comment: I think that I have to key frame the Evaluation time in order to get the person moving

Comment: Don't know why, doesn't the uploaded file work for you?

Comment: It works, but i remark that you keyframed the time evaluation of the curves in order to get the person moving. It is a little bit difficult for me. It seems that you changed a lot of parameters not only offset and influence. I also remark that you have not keyframed the offset. When I play the animation, its color does not change to green or yellow it is always gray.

Comment: I think the green color indicates that this value is calculated as a driver value or something like that. I don't remember to have this keyframed.

Comment: Green - Property has Channel with Keyframes.

Comment: to correct the head rotation problem, you have to enable head inherit. Thanks